# How do I refresh Application metadata - URL handlers, Web browsers - after installing my own AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm working on an AppleScript that handles URLs. There's a command one can give which re-creates the list that Safari shows to change the default web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added the appropriate entries in your application's **Info.plist** for the document and URL types, you should be able to just (re)register the application with Launch Services (Safari will also need to be restarted).  For Snow Leopard and Lion, the Terminal command would be:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -f /path/to/your/app
```

You can also reset the Launch Services database (see the lsregister help) or use a utility such as TinkerTool.